# SQLITE with Android (best methodology for setting up a database)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have seen a few different ways that you can utilize SQLite as the database for your app.  They are as follows:

- Database is created and data is imported via an XML file.
- Use of a SQLite GUI (SQLite Database Browser)
- Straight Database creation via a Database helper class.

What are the benefits of each one? I'm leaning towards using SQLite Database browser to load a few tables I will need for my app.  I will also have user input.

Do you suggest that I have an additional table for their input and Union, or allow the user to input into table I have provided. The one issue I foresee is on upgrade of the app (via the Market), I do not want the user to lose data that they have entered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option which I did:

- Store each of the schema and data population files as scripts in resources
- Created a wrapper class that runs those scripts from resources
- One of the resource files is a well known (by name) manifest, it has a list of the scripts to run in which order.
- I have a poperties table in the database which stores what's the last script that ran.

That means:

- On creation (first run) - it runs all scripts in succession
- When app is updates - it runs all scripts that haven't run yet.  The update carries more scripts in resources.

The scripts update schema and modify/munge existing customer data - of course without data loss.

BTW, I did this on iOS with the intent of sharing those sqlite scripts between android, winphone and other platforms.  You just need the wrapper class on each platform that runs the sequences.

It also means I can run the scripts in order from the cmdline to create a db if needed ...

**EDIT:**

For example, in my sample app, Update1.sql is a file added as a resource.  It has two sql batches in it.  My wrapper opens the manifest file, get's the list of scripts to run, queries the database to see the last script ran, then creates an array of scripts to run.  When it runs Update1.sql which is in the list, my wrapper class executes all the statements in that file thats embedded as a resource.  For example, here's my Update1.sql

```
alter table messages add column user text;

create table log
(
    id integer primary key autoincrement, 
    information text    
);
```

Now, let's say the new table created needs some data in it.  (in my case a log table doesn't).  That scripts could contain a series of insert into statements right after the create table.

Executing multiple batches in a script requires the use of the tail argument in prepare.  I have C/objective-c code if you would like to see it but I haven't written the android wrapper yet ...

Comment: Thanks bryanmac... So your suggestion is to use option one- Database is created and data is imported via an XML file. Create the database via coding, then load the database via XML (or some delimited file(s)).  I'm new to Android Development, but not databases in general. So on an update of the APP, does the new App export the user's data from the old app and then import that data into the new app's database? A full-reinstall? or does it just change the code of the APP and keep the dbase as is? (if no version change on dbase)?

Comment: Not really - it's not created via coding - the schema and data is create via sql scripts and you just have a wrapper library that executes those scripts.  As your schema and data changes over time - the xml is not powerful enough.  For example, you may need to join data via queries to populate new tables without data loss.  Between update1 & 2 you may want to add a new column and populate it with defaults.  The scripts are key because when an update comes out, only the delta changes must run.