# How to add and execute .sql files in my iOS project?

Tags: ios, database, xcode, sqlite

I've found many tutorials on using SQLite databases in iOS, but haven't found anything that directly references .sql files.  Can anybody tell me how I can link an existing SQL database to my app?

Edit: It's a MySQL dump. We had a browser-based flashcard program, which we're now replicating for Android and iOS devices. The file already has statements to create the tables and populate the data, but I don't know how to use that data within the app. Do I maybe want to use NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains?

Comment: what kind of sql files do you mean? like sql dumps? or sqlite databases?

Comment: You generally don't use .sql files in apps themselves. If you have SQL file that, for example, creates tables and perhaps populates the data, you can use `sqlite3` or some other sqlite database utility and execute the SQL right on your Mac, thereby creating a sqlite database that you can then use in your iOS app. But the app itself doesn't use .sql files. Note, sqlite's SQL is not precisely the same as other database engines, so you might have to tweak your .sql file if it was designed for another database engine.

Comment: You'll have to tell us what your .sql file is intended for, and then we can better advise how you can use it.

Comment: Did you get this working?  Did the executeScript function below work for you?

Answer (score 3):

I execute scripts as part of an iOS project.  The reason I do it is the same series of scripts that creates the database schema also updates the database schema (after release, new delta scripts are run to pull the schema forward).  It's explained in detail here:

[SQLITE with Android (best methodology for setting up a database)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663706/sqlite-with-android-best-methodology-for-setting-up-a-database/8663873#8663873)

I add the script as a resource in the project and then execute it.  There's some EXxxx logging calls but otherwise generic.  Note the use of tail - sqlite executes a statement at a time of the script looping through with tail as a marker where it left off.  Here's the function I use to execute:

```
- (BOOL)executeScript:(NSString *)contents error:(NSError **)error
{
    ENHeading(@"executeScript");

    sqlite3_stmt *stmt = NULL;
    const char *zTail;
    int rc;

    zTail = [contents UTF8String];

    while(zTail != NULL && 0 < strlen(zTail)) 
    {
        ENDebug("zTail: \"%s\"\n", zTail);

        NSString *tailStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:zTail];
        NSString *trimmed = [tailStr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                             [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

        if ([trimmed length] == 0)
        {
            ENInfo("ignoring trailing whitespace");
            break;
        }

        // Temporarily hold this until the end of the loop in case we need to report an error
        const char *newzTail;

        rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(_sqlite3, zTail, -1, &stmt, &newzTail);
        if(SQLITE_OK != rc) 
        {
            ENError(@"prepare err:%@", [self errorMessage]);
            if (error != NULL) {
                *error = [[[ENSqliteError alloc] initWithErrorCode:ENSqliteErrorInvalidSql 
                                                            reason:[self errorMessage]] autorelease];
            }

            return NO;
        }

        rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
        ENDebug(@"rc=%d", rc);
        switch (rc)
        {
            case SQLITE_ROW:
                ENError(@"statement returns rows, script ignores");
                break;

            case SQLITE_OK:
            case SQLITE_DONE:
                break;

            default:
                ENError(@"error");
                ENError(@"prepare err:%@", [self errorMessage]);
                if (error != NULL) {
                    *error = [[[ENSqliteError alloc] initWithErrorCode:ENSqliteErrorReadingRows 
                                                                reason:[self errorMessage]] autorelease];
                }

                return NO;
        }

        // For next time around the loop
        zTail = newzTail;

        // Clear up since we're about to prepare another
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    } 

    return YES;
}
```