# iOS App SQLite database structure change

Tags: ios, ipad, sqlite

I am updating an old iOS app which used sqlite database. I changed the database structure adding columns to existing tables. Now, I am testing it on my device. If I clear my old app from iPad and then run this new updated version on it, it is working fine. But if I have the old version installed on ipad already and test this updated version, it is somehow using the old database instead of the one updated. Can some one help me why it is doing this?

Comment: You need to share some code on how you're updating the database for someone to help you ...

Comment: This answer covers how I update databases on iOS | android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663706/sqlite-with-android-best-methodology-for-setting-up-a-database/8663873#8663873

Comment: Installed old version using new database? How did you do that, I think the old version based on old database only.

Comment: yeah, old version is using old database. it is all good. When I update the app (I mean some coding and database) on newer version, and try to test it on device, then app is using the old database not the one updated database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess and to try and make a simple answer for you is this.  It's likely you updated the database in the project file - which means when you run it, your new db will exist in the bundle.  files in the bundle cannot be updated, so its common practice to copy the database out of the bundle and store it somewhere in the ios sandbox.  I usually use the documents directory to keep it simple.

Most likely what is happening is that when you run it over a pervious install, it see's that the file is already copied over to the device so it does not touch it, however on new installs, it probably sees the database is missing so it copies it there and that is why on new installs it works fine but existing ones it does not.

Look in the app delegate or your root view controller for code that checks for the existing database and copies the database over if needed on startup.

If you need to update the database on existing installs, you would need to force the copy.

Beware though if you have data in the existing database not to overwrite it if its important.  If important data is stored there, you have to either do a little shell game of getting the data and importing into the new database, or maybe a simpler way, is to run the database schema modification commands on the existing database so it is the same.

again, beware and make a copy of the local database file before you run those commands, just in case.

best of luck

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, a SQLLite database is really just a file.  When you used the old app, it created the schema in the database file.  When you load the new app, the data remains, untouched.  If you want to use the new schema, you will have to detect the old schema and update the existing data.  I believe that there are documented ways to deal with this.  Bryanmac's question reference seems to be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

When you install a new version of your app, iOS actually installs it in a new directory and then copies the contents of the documents folder from the older version to the one in the newer version. If you want to just use your new db, the best way is to have this db renamed or stored in a different directory inside your app's document store.

Here's a relevant article on updating An sqlite CoreData backing store on iOS:
http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1736