# iPhone App Local Database and Updating the App

Tags: ios

I have an iPhone app which consists of local database (`sqlite3`). The database consists of a `MyVegetableGarden table` which stores data about user's vegetables.

When I push out an update to my application it clears the MyVegetableGarden table and user's database will be lost.

How can I prevent this from happening or maintain user's data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663706/sqlite-with-android-best-methodology-for-setting-up-a-database/8663873#8663873

Comment: Where is the database stored within the app's sandbox? An app update does not clear a database table. Your app would be doing that. Install the old version of your app. Then use the debugger to run the new version. Have a break point in your code where you normally setup the database. This will point out where you are mistakenly clearing the database.

Comment: My database (sqlite3) is in the Supporting Files folder of xCode (Bundle). I am not clearing the database. I was wondering what will happen when I push out an update to the app. Will the user's table gets deleted or cleared.